# Can I exit a CMake scope via function call?

Tags: cmake

I'm searching for something like:

```
function(my_function)
    return(PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

my_function() # Should return here

message("don't print this")
```

I want the call to `my_function` to behave as if I had called `return` at this point.

The file you see here is a sub `CMakeLists.txt` that I want to stop processing from inside a function I call. This function is defined in another file which is included via `include`.

Is this possible with CMake?

Comment: What about using `macro` instead of `function`? Your question is an example in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html#macro-vs-function

Comment: That comes very close to what is wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I get your requirement correctly, you want to conditionally stop the script based on whatever happened in your function. As you cannot directly donthat from within the function, you can set a variable in the function and then check it after the function call returned, something like this:

```
function(my_function result_var)
    set(${result_var} "STOP" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

my_function(should_stop)

if(should_stop STREQUAL "STOP")
    return()
endif()

message("don't print this")
```

Comment: This is the kind of workaround I want to avoid. The call of my_function itself should trigger the return, not some explicit return after the function call.

Comment: You could try  `message(FATAL_ERROR "Stopping execution")` in `my_function` but that looks even uglier to me, esp. is not really for flow control.

Comment: I have clarified the question. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can build something very similar with `macro` and `block`:

```
# Use macro instead of function so that return() applies during the call
macro(my_function)
    # Define a temporary variable that is not in use in your calling scope
    set(my_function_return OFF)

    # Do all your stuff inside a block, so it is scoped as with function
    # At the end of your block the temporary variable is set in parent scope
    block(PROPAGATE my_function_return)
        # Set your temporary variable ON or OFF
        set(my_function_return ON)
    endblock()

    # Test your temporary variable
    if(my_function_return)
        # If you return, the temporary variable vanishes by return
        return()
    else()
        # Otherwise remove the temporary variable explicitly
        unset(my_function_return)
    endif()
endmacro()

my_function()

message("won't print this")
```

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/block.html

The only behavior difference to your original code is, that the variable `my_function_return` will be unset in the caller scope. You should therefore choose a name that you are sure that it is not used in the caller scope.